# Creating a scheduled task on Windows 7 using Powershell 4

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Am I right in thinking that some of the newer Powershell commands related to the management of scheduled tasks (such as `New-ScheduledTaskAction`) are not available on Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2, even if Powershell 4 is installed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you right, some PowerShell cmdlet it depend on the windows kernel.

The command `New-ScheduledTaskAction` supported windows 8 / server 2012 and newer.
you can read about id in 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649817.aspx .

In windows 7 / server 2008 R2 you can use the `new-ScheduledJobOption` and the `Register-ScheduledJob` cmdlet.

you can read more about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psscheduledjob/psscheduledjob

Here you can see example:

```
New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated -ContinueIfGoingOnBattery
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath C:\Users\User\Desktop\CreateFolderTest.ps1 -Name TestJob -RunNow
```

if you want to see the job in the `Task Scheduler`, go to `Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> PowerShell -> ScheduledJobs

for more option you can edit the Task in the "Task Schduler" and run the `Get-ScheduledJobOption`.

The last thing, the `Get-ScheduledJob` show only the jobs that you created with the `Register-ScheduledJob`!

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

David,

Based on my own experience (I have the Server 2008 R2 and Powershell 4 is installed), the newer cmdlets for scheduled tasks (such as New-ScheduledTaskAction) are not recognizable by Server 2008 R2. I also tried to add the newer cmdlets into the system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules folder but it is still not working.

Other post I read said these Cmdlets are coming with server 2012 or Windows 8 or later.

thanks
Liang